# I'm getting a page not found error when trying to visit my custom form

Tags: 8, forms, routes

This is the form that I created using Drupal 8:

```
namespace \Drupal\lookup\Form\lookupForm;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class lookupform extends FormBase
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId()
    {
        return 'lookup_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $form['Username'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('ULM Username'),
        ];

        $form['actions']['submit'] = [
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
          '#button_type' => 'primary',
        ];

        return $form; 
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {

    }

}
```

[image: Error Message]

**Routing file:**

```
user.form: 
 path: '/lookupForm'
 defaults: 
   _title: 'Lookup User Autocomplete'
   _form: '\Drupal\lookup\Form\lookupForm'
 requirements: 
   _permission: 'access content'
```

**Info file:**

```
name: Form 
description: This is a form.
core: 8.x
package: Custom
type: module
```

I am getting a page not found error. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem 1: Incorrect namespace. The class name should not be included in the namespace. Your namespace should be:

`Drupal\lookup\Form`

Problem 2: The name of your class is not the same name as the routing file (capitalization).

Class name: `lookupform`

Routing file: `_form: '\Drupal\lookup\Form\lookupForm'`

(Capital F)

Problem 3 (credit: laymannx) - you're visiting the wrong path. Should be visiting `/lookupform` (after fixing the above problems).

Comment: Problem 3: Incorrect path called. The routing file says `/lookupForm`. The page not found error message says `/lookup/myform`.

Comment: And was only a submit handler mandatory? Don't you also need a validate handler?

Comment: Validation handler is required by FormInterface, but it's implemented as an empty function by FormBase::validateForm (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBase.php/function/FormBase%3A%3AvalidateForm/8.8.x), so classes don't need to implement it.